# Insert/update JSON date in Oracle APEX 19.1 form failed

Tags: json, oracle, oracle-apex-19.1

Beginner here. My first question ever on StackOverflow

I have a table (`my_info_table`) with the columns `id`, `fname`, `lname`, and `d_address`, which is of the data type `clob` and stores JSON data in the form of objects.

Let the JSON data be `{“street”: “value1”}` and `{“city”: “value2”}`

I wanted to utilize the power of APEX 19.1 wizards in order to create forms, reports, interactive reports containing json data.

I wrote a select statement in the wizards using either dotnotation or json_value(), but when I want to insert/update the items of the form containing json data, I get an error message saying `The right parentheses is missing.`

Can you help please, preferably with a code example, articles, videos explaining.

Comment: Hello apexnovice.  Could you post a code example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @isakbob. 

I have a JSON with the following structure:

'{"street":"value1"}, {"city":"value2"}' stored in a column called 'd_address', which is of 'clob' datatype.

I want to create a form using the APEX 19.1 wizards that allows for inserting and updating date in all different columns, including the JSON columns. 

The select statement my form is based on is as follows:

'SELECT id, fname, lname, json_value (d_address, '$.street'), json_value(d_address, '$city')'.

Comment: The problem is that when I create the form, it shows without any problem. But if I want to add or edit data to the form, and fill in the item corresponding to `street` or `city` i get an error saying `The right parentheses is missing`.